# Why is my cron job in directadmin not working?

Tags: php, cron

I have the below php file which runs well in the browser AND from the command line.

```
<?php

    $ch = curl_init ('http://www.domain.com/test_if_script_runs.php');
    $output = curl_exec ($ch);

?>
```

The file test_if_script_runs.php only adds a number in a database so that I can see the script runs.

I've set up a cron job in directadmin. In the input fields I've only added 10 for minutes and left all other fields with a star.

So the question is, why is the cron job in directadmin not working?

UPDATE 1:

I checked that in /var/log/cron the path to the file is there. There are no error messages in that file. It seems that the cron is just working fine. However there is no output as when I run the cron from command line or from browser I checked that the file is giving the required output.

Comment: i never used directadmin but i guess it will modify the crontab. Anyway... did you put the full path of php executable? cron daemon need it.

Comment: @DavideBerra yes I used the full path.

Comment: try to add 2>&1 > /tmp/log.txt at the end of the script into the cron job line. Like this: "/path/to/php/executable/php /path/to/php/file/page.php 2>&1 > /tmp/log.txt". Then make it run at least once and show us the content of /tmp/log.txt

Comment: @DavideBerra I tried that, but the file is empty. I also viewed in /var/log/cron and see that the file is there.

Answer (score 0):

I had to put php in front of the command in order to have php process the file. I have something like the below:

```
php /home/admin/domain.com/public_html/script.php
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
cd /home/user/public_html/any/folder; /usr/local/bin/php -f file.php
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/<USER>/domains/<DOMAIN>/public_html/script.php
```